# Após commit utilizando tortoise, ícone de pasta não alterado

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Após realizar `commit` em uma pasta, o `commit` é realizado com sucesso, mas não ocorre mudança de ícone após o processo, continuando com ícone de pasta normal do windows.

O erro nem sempre ocorre. Como proceder?

Comment: O que você espera que aconteça? posta como esta suas pastas.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que está tentando fazer? O que espera que aconteça, que tipo de alteração está fazendo e como está o código e icones atualmente.

Comment: Já tenho uma resposta definida. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Windows Explorer, abra o menu usando o botão direito do mouse, submenu "**TortoiseSVN**", "**Clean up...**"

[image: "TortoiseSVN" -> "Clean up..."]

E na tela que aparecer, escolha "**Refresh shell overlays**" (desmarque as demais opções se não quiser realizar mais nada além disso) e então clique no botão "**OK**".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito. Deu certo. Pode até ser que não resolve a causa do problema, mas corrige a consequência. Obrigado.